# getApplicationContext on a null reference in AppCompatActivity using Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso, appcompatactivity

I'm loading a picture from a url into a bitmap. This code below worked on previous classes that extended Fragment. This time, I'm just copying the code and trying to use it in a class that extends AppCompatActivity. The only difference is how I'm getting context.

```
public void loadBitmap(String url) {
    if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }
    };
    mContext = MyActivity.this;
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(loadtarget); //giving me null
}
```

In the original code, where I used it in a Fragment, I had it as

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(loadtarget);
```

So now, since this class extends AppCompatActivity, I thought I could use "this" or MyActivity.this but that didn't work. I've tried initializing a Context variable "mContext" in onCreate and right before I load the image into the bitmap (like above) but neither worked. I've tried this.getApplicationContext() and I've also tried to pass mContext as a parameter in the loadBitmap() method but that didn't work either.

My URL string is correct. I'm just not sure how to tackle this problem after trying, what seems like, everything.

Last piece of information, the exception:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:112)
                                                                 at com.salty.seas.Driver.MyActivity.loadBitmap(MyActivity.java:144)
                                                                 at com.salty.seas.Driver.MyActivity$1.onKeyEntered(MyActivity.java:61)
                                                                 at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery$2.run(GeoQuery.java:126)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Is loadBitmap inside your MyActivity?

Comment: Yup! @ArtemNovikov

Comment: Provide full stacktrace.

Comment: Updated @ArtemNovikov 
Also some more information: loadBitmap() is just being called in onKeyEntered()

Comment: How do you get in this Activity? How do you create it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. @ArtemNovikov

Comment: How do you start this Activity?

Comment: @ArtemNovikov Ah, I don't. I never really start it, I just use the methods that I've written inside it for other classes.

Comment: Since method loadBitmap is not static, to use it, you must be create an instance of MyActivity somewhow, do you?

Comment: Yes, @ArtemNovikov. I have an instance of it where I just call methods from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122241/discussion-between-artem-novikov-and-saltysea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments to the question you said that the activity, the `loadBitmap()` belongs to, you actually instantiate yourself (in some other fragment) and use it as an utility class.

You should **never create activites manually** as they are **managed by android** and they have a lifecycle android maintains.

In your case the activity is not in a correct state (one of its internal fields is null), that's why you get NPE.

For utility methods create utility classes and call those from wherever you want.